# How to extract elements of an Array

Tags: javascript

I have the above data ,

```
var jsonData = [
    {date:'August 19, 2004',open:100.01,high:104.06,low:95.96,close:100.34,volume:22088000},
    {date:'August 20, 2004',open:101.48,high:109.08,low:100.50,close:108.31,volume:11377000},
    {date:'August 23, 2004',open:110.76,high:113.48,low:109.05,close:109.40,volume:9090700},
    {date:'August 24, 2004',open:111.24,high:111.60,low:103.57,close:104.87,volume:7599100},
    {date:'August 25, 2004',open:104.96,high:108.00,low:103.88,close:106.00,volume:4565900}
];
```

I would like to get all the sigle values of the date , i have used this one

```
for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length; i++) 
    var date = jsonData[i].date;
date = date.split(' ');
return date;
```

But i am getting only the Last Value that is August,25,,2004

How can i get all the values ??

Comment: Please don't call any old JavaScript object "jsonData" it is only going to confuse someone at some point.

Comment: when you return inside a loop, the loop and method its in end.  You must aggregate your data in the way you want it, or process it within your loop.  What do you mean when you say, "I would like to get all the sigle values of the date"?

Comment: @ehudokai: The `return` is actually not inside the loop.

Comment: Argggh. Unbraced `for` statements are the work of the devil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>There is a problem with your loop. It only runs once, and even if you removed that, it would keep overwriting the value stored in `date`</strike>

If you want to store all the dates, you need to make it into an array and store the date. I'm not sure what you mean by `single values of dates` but this structure will solve the problem for you.

```
var dates = [];
for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
   var date = jsonData[i].date;
   date = date.split(' '); 
   //do whatever you want with your date. transform.
   dates.push(date); //push the final version of the date you want to store
}
return dates;  //return an array of dates
```

Comment: No, there is no starting bracket after the `for`, so the contents of the loop is only the single statement following it. The `return` is outside the loop, so it will not exit out of the loop.

Comment: Urgh, I didn't notice that because of the terrible indentation. I thought he had just left it out. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you are putting all the dates in the same variable, so in each iteration you are overwriting the previous value. Add the dates to an array instead:

```
var dates = [];
for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
  dates.push(jsonData[i].date);
}
return dates;
```

That returns an array of date strings. If you want to split each date and return an array of array of strings:

```
var dates = [];
for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
  dates.push(jsonData[i].date.split(' '));
}
return dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `date` variable in each iteration of your loop. Instead, keep a variable (initialized outside of the loop) and push each date array (generated inside the loop) to it.

```
dates = [];
for ( idx in jsonData ) {
    dates.push(jsonData[idx].split(' '));
}

// dates is an array of arrays now
// for example: [['August', '19,', '2004'], ...]
return dates;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies , nothing at worked , it is still returing an series of array . I have solved this way HumbleFinance.xTickFormatter = function (n) { 

        if(n==0.0)
  {
  
  n =0;
  }
  if(n==1.0)
  {
  n =1;
  }
if(n==2.0)
  {
  n =2;
  }

  if(n==3.0)
  {
  n =3;
  }
  
  if(n==4.0)
  {
  n =4;
  }

        var date = jsonData[n].date;
        date = date.split(' ');
       
        
        return date;

Answer (score 0):

hi here you define a loop so every value of array is overwrite in date variable so it gives last overwritten values

to extract all value you do not use loop this type you define

you simply write

var date1 = jsonData[0].date;
var date2 = jsonData[1].date;